# Find intersection of two sorted arrays which in some cases require less than O(m+n) comparisons

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

Here is one way of doing this in `O(m+n)` where `m` and `n` are lengths of two arrays:

```
import random

def comm_seq(arr_1, arr_2):
    if len(arr_1) == 0 or len(arr_2) == 0:
        return []

    m = len(arr_1) - 1
    n = len(arr_2) - 1

    if arr_1[m] == arr_2[n]:
        return comm_seq(arr_1[:-1], arr_2[:-1]) + [arr_1[m]]

    elif arr_1[m] < arr_2[n]:
        return comm_seq(arr_1, arr_2[:-1])

    elif arr_1[m] > arr_2[n]:
        return comm_seq(arr_1[:-1], arr_2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr_1 = [random.randrange(0,5) for _ in xrange(10)]
    arr_2 = [random.randrange(0,5) for _ in xrange(10)]
    arr_1.sort()
    arr_2.sort()
    print comm_seq(arr_1, arr_2)
```

Is there a technique that in some cases uses less than `O(m+n)` comparisons? For example: `arr_1=[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,100]` and `arr_2=[1,3,100]`

(Not looking for the hash table implementation)

Comment: "(Not looking for the hash table implementation)" - why not?  Is there a constraint you haven't told us about, like not being allowed to create another data structure as an index to your arrays?

Comment: @mbeckish There is no other constraint. I am just looking for a solution using the comparison model with less than `O(m+n)` comparisons.

Comment: That function looks to me as `O(min(n,m))` not `O(n+m)`

Comment: Here is a faster solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33963306/97248 . It's just as fast as possible, according to the answer of Brent Nesh.

Answer (score 6):

A binary search algorithm requires `O(logm)` time to find a number in an array with length m. 
Therefore, if we search each number of an array with length n from an array with length m, its overall time complexity is `O(nlogm)`. **If m is much greater than n**, `O(nlogm)` is actually less than `O(m+n)`. Therefore, we can implement a new and better solution based on binary search in such a situation. [source](http://codercareer.blogspot.pt/2011/11/no-24-intersection-of-sorted-arrays.html)

However, this does not necessarily means binary search is better in than O(m+n) case. In fact, binary search approach is only better when n << m (n is very small compared to m).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there are a few different ways to solve this problem, ***but none of them are better than O(m + n)***.  I don't know how you can have an algorithm faster than that (barring weird quantum computing answers), because you have to compare all the elements in both arrays or you might miss a duplicate.

**Brute Force**
Use two nested for loops.  Take every element from the first array and linear search it in the second array. **O(M*N) time, O(1) space**

**Map Lookup**
Use a lookup structure like a hashtable or a binary search tree.  Put all of the first array into the map structure, then loop through all of the second array and look up each element in the map to see if it exists.  This works whether the arrays are sorted or not. **O(M*log(M) + N*log(M)) for Binary Search Tree time or O(M + N) time for Hashtable, both are O(M) space.**

**Binary Search**
Like brute force, but take every element from the first array and binary search it in the second array.  **O(m*log(N)) time, O(1) space**

**Parallel Walk**
Like the merge part of merge sort.  Have two pointers start at the front of each of the arrays.  Compare the two elements, if they're equal store the duplicate, otherwise advance the pointer to the smaller value by one spot and repeat until you hit the end of one of the arrays. **O(M + N) time, O(1) space**

Regardless, you ***must*** examine every element in both arrays or you won't know if you've found all the duplicates.  You could argue fringe cases where one array is a lot bigger or a lot smaller, but that won't hold for an alogrithm where you're considering all ranges of input.

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm with O(N*log(M/N)) comparisons is possible if you use a combination of one-sided and normal binary search. In the worst case (when both arrays are of equal size) this is equal to O(N) = O(M + N) comparisons. Here M is size of the largest array, N is the number of distinct elements in smaller array.

Get the smallest of two arrays and search each of its elements in the second array. Start with one-sided binary search: try positions M/N, 2*M/N, 4*M/N, ... until an element, larger than necessary is found. Then use normal binary search to find an element between positions 0 and 2<sup>k</sup>*M/N.

If matching element is found, use the same combination of one-sided and normal binary search to find where the run of duplicate matching elements ends and copy appropriate number of matching elements to output. You can use the same combination of binary searches to count the number of duplicate elements in smaller array, and get the minimum of these duplicate counts to determine how much elements should be in the result.

To continue with the next element from smaller array, use starting position in larger array, where the previous step ended.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hash_table to save the large array, and then scan the other small array to calculate the intersection of two array.

```
import random

def comm_seq(arr_1, arr_2):
    if len(arr_1) < len(arr_2): arr_1, arr_2 = arr_2, arr_1
    cnt = {}
    for item in arr_1: 
        cnt.setdefault(item, 0)
        cnt[item] += 1
    # save the large array in a hash_table
    ret = []
    for item in arr_2:
        p = cnt.get(item, 0)
        if p: 
            ret.append(item):
            cnt[item] -= 1
    # scan the small array and get the answer
    return ret

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr_1 = [random.randrange(0,5) for _ in xrange(10)]
    arr_2 = [random.randrange(0,5) for _ in xrange(10)]
    arr_1.sort()
    arr_2.sort()
    print comm_seq(arr_1, arr_2)
```

If we consider the complexity of the py-dictionary operating as O(1), the total complexity is O(min(n, m))

Comment: If the range of the element is very small, we can use list to replace the dictionary to get the real O(1) operating.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I am not looking for the hash table technique as mentioned in my question.

Comment: I'm sorry that I ignore some information.