# list intersection algorithm implementation only using python lists (not sets)

Tags: python

I've been trying to write down a list intersection algorithm in python that takes care of repetitions. I'm a newbie to python and programming so forgive me if this sounds inefficient, but I couldn't come up with anything else. Here, L1 and L2 are the two lists in question, and L is the intersection set.

1. Iterate through L1
2. Iterate through L2
3. If element is in L1 and in L2
4. add it to L
5. remove it from L1 and L2
6. iterate through L
7. add elements back to L1 and L2

I'm 100% sure this is not the algorithm used within Mathematica to evaluate list intersection, but I can't really come up with anything more efficient. I don't want to modify L1 and L2 in the process, hence me adding back the intersection to both lists. Any ideas? I don't want to make use of any built in functions/data types other than lists, so no import sets or anything like that. This is an algorithmic and implementation exercise, not a programming one, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: What do you mean by "taking care of repetitions"?

Comment: What does "without using builtins" mean? `list` is just as much a builtin as `set`, and `list.__getitem__` is just as much a builtin as `set.intersection`, and so on.

Comment: @Blender I mean that I want intersection([1,1,2],[1,2,2]) to return [1,2] and not [1,1,2], which it does return if I don't remove the elements from each of the lists.

Comment: @abarnert I meant that I don't want to make use of the `set` class that's within python, and do it only using lists. I am aware that `list` is builtin but it's just a data structure to implement this algorithm.

Comment: "without using builtins" makes no sense, -1

Comment: @jterrace I agree that it doesn't make sense when it's interpreted as a global claim within python (i.e I'm in the `__main__` function, which is obviously builtin), but I meant I don't want to make use of builtin methods within other data structures in python.

Comment: @noobProgrammer: So you don't want to do this "without builtins", but "without `set`". Any other restrictions? For example, can we use `element in l2` (when `l2` is a `list`)? Knowing what the actual constraints are makes the question a little easier to answer than just throwing out guesses at what you might want.

Comment: @abarnert Again, the I only want to make use of the list class/data structure within python, with it's own `__contains__` methods and everything else that is releveant(`__iter__`).

Comment: What about `list.sort`?

Comment: "I want to do a set operation with using a set"...

Comment: @jterrace: Pretty much. Or on a more meta level, "I want to get a useful answer to my question without getting a useful answer to my question" maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

1. Iterate though L1
2. Iterate though L2
3. If (in L1 and L2) and not in L -> add to L

Not particularly efficient, but in code it would look something like this (with repetitions to make the point):

```
>>> L1 = [1,2,3,3,4]
>>> L2 = [2,3,4,4,5]
>>> L = list()
>>> for v1 in L1:
        for v2 in L2:
            if v1 == v2 and v1 not in L:
                L.append(v1)
>>> L
[2,3,4]
```

You avoid deleting from L1 and L2 simply by checking if the element is already in L and adding to L if it is not. Then it doesn't matter if there are repetitions in L1 and L2.

Comment: +1. But you should probably explain how this avoids needing to remove elements from L1 and L2 and add them back in later…

Comment: Awesome, seems like it works. Definitely more efficient than mine. Thanks.

Comment: It's not any more efficient—in fact, it's slower, O(N^3) instead of O(N^2). (Technically, O(LMN) instead of O(MN) + O(L^2), if the list lengths M and N are significantly different or the intersection length L is much shorter. But same idea.) It's a lot _simpler_, which is a huge win, but that doesn't make it more efficient.

Comment: @abarnert Alright thanks. I don't think I'm going to be working with significantly different list sizes anyways.

Comment: @abarnert -- after that (impressive) analysis, I am so so glad I used the disclaimer "not particularly efficient" :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a faster solution:

```
def intersect_sorted(a1, a2):
  """Yields the intersection of sorted lists a1 and a2, without deduplication.

  Execution time is O(min(lo + hi, lo * log(hi))), where lo == min(len(a1),
  len(a2)) and hi == max(len(a1), len(a2)). It can be faster depending on
  the data.
  """
  import bisect, math
  s1, s2 = len(a1), len(a2)
  i1 = i2 = 0
  if s1 and s1 + s2 > min(s1, s2) * math.log(max(s1, s2)) * 1.4426950408889634:
    bi = bisect.bisect_left
    while i1 < s1 and i2 < s2:
      v1, v2 = a1[i1], a2[i2]
      if v1 == v2:
        yield v1
        i1 += 1
        i2 += 1
      elif v1 < v2:
        i1 = bi(a1, v2, i1)
      else:
        i2 = bi(a2, v1, i2)
  else:  # The linear solution is faster.
    while i1 < s1 and i2 < s2:
      v1, v2 = a1[i1], a2[i2]
      if v1 == v2:
        yield v1
        i1 += 1
        i2 += 1
      elif v1 < v2:
        i1 += 1
      else:
        i2 += 1
```

It runs in `O(min(n + m, n * log(m)))` time where n is the minimum of the lengths and m is the maximum. It iterates over both lists at the same time, skipping as many elements in the beginning as possible.

An analysis is available here: http://ptspts.blogspot.ch/2015/11/how-to-compute-intersection-of-two.html

Comment: there is some mistake in it, tested a few algorithm including this one, all gave the same intersection result instead of this one

Comment: @SaraKat: Please share an input for which this one returns incorrect results, and also share what the others have returned. This will make it possible to fix this one. (Did you make sure to pass sorted lists to this one?)

Comment: I ported these to Kotlin and tested them extensively against naive implementations. They run about 5x faster than platform `.intersect()` on lists of similar size, and about 1000x as fast when the sizes are hugely skewed (10 vs 100,000). https://gist.github.com/cherrydev/cff792b6208424189ed4be0c21f2ab7b

Answer (score 2):

Anything that iterates through `L1`, iterating through all of `L2` each time, will take quadratic time. The only way to improve that is to avoid iterating through all of `L2`. (There's a similar issue removing duplicates from `L` at the end.)

If you use a `set` for `L2` (and for `L`), of course each `in L2` step is constant time, so the overall algorithm is linear. And you can always build your own hash table implementation instead of using `set`. But that's a lot of work.

With a binary search tree, or even just a sorted list and a `binary_find` function, you can do it in O(N log N). And that `binary_find` is much easier to write yourself. So:

```
S2 = sorted(L2)
L = [element for element in L1 if binary_find(element, S2)]
S = remove_adjacent(sorted(L))
```

Or, even more simply, sort L1 too, and then you don't need `remove_adjacent`:

```
S1, S2 = sorted(L1), sorted(L2)
L = []
for element in S1:
    if binary_find(element, S2) and (not L or L[-1] != element):
        L.append(element)
```

Either way, this is O(N log N), where N is the length of the longer list. By comparison, the original is O(N^2), and the other answers are O(N^3). Of course it's a bit more complicated, but it's still pretty easy to understand.

You need to write the `binary_find` (and, if applicable, `remove_adjacent`), because I assume you don't want to use stuff out of the stdlib if you don't even want to use extra builtins. But that's really easy. For example:

```
def binary_find(element, seq):
    low, high = 0, len(seq), 
    while low != high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if seq[mid] == element:
            return True
        elif seq[mid] < element:
            low = mid+1
        else:
            high = mid
    return False

def remove_adjacent(seq):
    ret = []
    last = object()
    for element in seq:
        if element != last:
            ret.append(element)
        last = element
    return ret
```

If you don't even want to use `sorted` or `list.sort`, you can write your own sort pretty easily too.

Comment: Excellent. I appreciate you taking the time to write the code out explicitly, as well as explaining the runtimes for the other algorithms posted on this thread.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I read the title wrong, and skimmed over the builtins part. I'm gonna leave it here anyway, might help someone else.

You can acheive this using the `set` type.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [3,4,5,6]
>>> c = list(set(a) & set(b))
>>> c
[3, 4]
```

Comment: If you can't use `set` because of "not using builtins", you can't use `list`, `list.__getitem__`, etc., either, so the problem is unsolvable…

Comment: you have to suppose lists are ok since you're trying to intersect them... :)  but fair point all the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a temporary list.
2. Iterate through one of the two lists. It doesn't matter which one.
3. For every element, check to see if that element exists in the other list (`if element in list2`) and isn't already in your temporary list (same syntax)
4. If both conditions are true, append it to your temporary list.

---

I feel bad for posting the solution, but it's honestly more readable than my text:

```
def intersection(l1, l2):
    temp = []

    for item in l1:
        if item in l2 and item not in temp:
            temp.append(item)

    return temp
```

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic and efficient way to compute the intersection of two lists preserving the order AND eliminating duplicates is the following:

```
L1 = [1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6]
L2 = [2,4,6]
aux = set()
L = [x for x in L1 if x in L2 and not (x in aux or aux.add(x)) ]
```

The solution uses the set "aux" to store elements already added to the resulting list.

Note that you don't need to "import" sets, because they are native data types in Python. But if you insist on not using sets, you can opt for this less efficient version that uses a list instead:

```
L1 = [1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6]
L2 = [2,4,6]
aux = []
L = [x for x in L1 if x in L2 and not (x in aux or aux.append(x)) ]
```